# How to show content of about.md on homepage as default in jekyll?

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I am working on github pages with jekyll. I want to put the about me on my homepage by default.

I've searched a lot but found little help for this demand.

Comment: Where is your `about.md` file located?

Comment: It is located in the root dir.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting the about me on your homepage by default"? You want the content of about me shown in the homepage instead of the list of articles ? Do you have an existing github pages repo ?

Comment: @wasthishelpful Yes

Comment: There were 3 questions in my comment. "Yes" may be an answer for 2 of them. If you want us to help you, feel free to be a little more expansive and provide more details on what you have done (your jekyll installation, the layouts, the pages, ...) and what you want to achieve

Comment: @wasthishelpful, I don't install jekyll locally. I just want to make my homepage to merely show my "about me" content as default.

Comment: Workable solution: Delete `index.html` and change `about.md` to `index.md` with `permalink: /index`. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One easy method is to put the `about.md` file in the `_posts` directory with the first date. Then, when Jekyll indexes `_posts`, you can always assume that `site.posts.first` is the `about.md`.

Some sample code below:

```
---
layout: default
---
<section class="main-content">
    {% assign post = site.posts.first %}
    {% assign content = post.content %}
    <article class="module color-3">
        {{ content }}
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you test building locally to see error logs?

Comment: I don't have jekyll locally.